# Batch hide or show components in Mura?

Tags: mura

I have a large amount of pages that all contain 10+ components. Because I used the copy+paste functionality, the copied pages and resulting components are automatically set to be hidden. Is there a way that I can batch set all the hidden components to be visible? Or do I have to change the visibility of every component individually?

Answer (score 0):

When you copy+paste content in Mura, the pasted content is set to not display. This is so that if you copy a Page called "Some Article" and paste it, that the subsequent article titled "Some Article - Copy" doesn't all of the sudden appear on your site.

However, I don't think the components should be coming through as "hidden" though. So, I'm a bit confused as to your issue on that end. Maybe you're copying a section of the site, and the components were placed in their parent and were being inherited to the child content items. If that's the case, then you should be able to simply apply the same components to the pasted children's parent.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately no... The page I'm copying has components in it and they're all set to display. But when I copy the page and it's components (by using Copy All) and paste it, the pasted components automatically are set to hidden.

Comment: Not sure what version of Mura you're trying this on, but I just tested on v6.2 and the pasted content item is set to not display, but the component is fine. Maybe update your core to the latest version and try again?